# Can't install sudo on Debian 10

Tags: debian, sudo

Basically it says I don't have enough space to install it, and looking for how to set up more space in

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

I've discovered that I need sudo for do it. What can I do? I'm running Debian 10 on VMBox 6.1

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `sudo` you'll have a root password so you can use `su`

```
su -
```

If you don't have the root password you'll need to speak to someone who does.

Answer (score 0):

To set up more space you need to resize your partition.

Resize the virtual disk image:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd filename.vdi --resize <size>
```

Then configure your VirtualBox to boot from [`gparted`](https://gparted.org/download.php) iso file, Once done, select the partition you want to expand then click on Resize/Move to get the partition resized in the larger of the virtual disk.

Next step install `sudo`:

```
su -c "apt install sudo"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your account just doesn't have sudo privileges, here's what you do: `$ su -` then insert the root password, then `# adduser username sudo` or `# adduser -aG username sudo` should work, if you replace 'username' with your username. Alternatively, after `$ su -`, do `visudo` and add the line `username ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` or `username ALL=(ALL) ALL` to the file. If sudo actually ***isn't*** installed, `su -` then use `fdisk` or `parted` or gparted if you have that to expand the Debian partition. Then `apt-get install sudo` or download the sudo source code and follow the compilation instructions then put it wherever it goes (I don't know where binary files like `sudo` are stored on Debian 10, since I use Bullseye (Debian 11), which links /bin and /sbin and something else to their respective variants under /usr). Gparted actually works without sudo, though, since it uses the udisk daemon, which already operates as root.